# Control Lifetime - Sequence diagram - Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, modeling, enterprise-architect

I have previously been modeling with Visual Paradigm. There I had lots of possibilities to control the Lifetime of my Objects.

What I mean exactly is that dashed array symbolizing the creation of an object and the cross at the end of the lifeline, symbolizing that the object has been finalized.

I did some research, and according to [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/modeling_languages/sequencediagram.html) webpage EA does this Support somehow. In the picture below (found in the link) note how ":Cart Item" is created and finished. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the message properties and select `Lifecycle/New` and `/Delete`. That will create/destroy the lifeline.

Comment: Awww my god.. cant believe i did not see this. Thanks alot